# How to work with exported Stack Driver logs from Google Cloud Projects into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have created an "export" from my Stackdriver Logging page in my Google Cloud project.  I configured the export to go to a BigQuery dataset.

When I go to BigQuery, I see the dataset.

There are no tables in my dataset, since Stackdriver export created the BigQuery dataset for me.

How do I see the data that was exported?  Since there are no tables I cannot perform a "select * from X".  I could create a table but I don't know what columns to add nor do I know how to tell Stackdriver logging to write to that table.

I must be missing a step.

Google has a short 1 minute video on exporting to Big Query but it stops exactly at the point where I am in the process.

Comment: Once you have defined an export with a sink to BQ then NEW log messages will be written to BQ which will create the tables.  Have new messages been arriving in the logs that match the filters in the export?

Comment: @Kolban When I create the export - is there no way to export the existing logs?  There are quite a few logs already existing but, no, no new data has been written to the logs yet.

Comment: @Kolban I see that it did eventually create a 'table' in the dataset but there are no rows in it.  I went to my source application and performed some actions and I see the updated log entries in the Stackdriver log UI.  Does the action of "create export" automatically cause a regular 'sync' process to update the data with more data?  I took it as a one time sync.

Answer (score 0):

When a new Stackdriver export is defined, it will *then* start to export newly written log records to the target sink (BQ in this case).  As per the documentation found here:

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/

it states:

> Since exporting happens for new log entries only, you cannot export
>   log entries that Logging received before your sink was created.

If one wants to export existing logs to a file, one can use gcloud (or API) as described here:

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging#reading_log_entries

The output of this "dump" of existing log records can then used in whatever manner you see fit.  For example, it could be imported into a BQ table.

Comment: I do not see any rows in my dataset/table even though I've used the application and can see the logs in the Stackdriver logs UI.  Is there something I need to do to have the logs funnelling automatically to the BigQuery table?  I feel like I'm missing a step somewhere.

Comment: @TerryChambers-Onix ... just to be clear .. you are talking about NEW log messages being created?  Once you have setup an export, from that moment onwards NEW log messages that match the filter will arrive in the target BQ tables.

I would run "gcloud logging sinks list" to list the exports I have defined and then run "gcloud logging sinks describe SINK_NAME" to see what its definition may be.  You might want to run these and update your question with the output (make sure you don't expose company info).

Answer (score 0):

To export logs in the bigquery from the stackdrive , you have to create Logger Sink using code or GCP logging UI

Then create Sink, add a filter.
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2

[image]

Then add logs to stack driver using code

```
public static void writeLog(Severity severity, String logName, Map<String, String> jsonMap) {
List<Map<String, String>> maps = limitMap(jsonMap);
for (Map<String, String> map : maps) {
  LogEntry logEntry = LogEntry.newBuilder(Payload.JsonPayload.of(map))
      .setSeverity(severity)
      .setLogName(logName)
      .setResource(monitoredResource)
      .build();
  logging.write(Collections.singleton(logEntry));
}
```

}

```
private static MonitoredResource monitoredResource = 
MonitoredResource.newBuilder("global")
   .addLabel("project_id", logging.getOptions().getProjectId())
   .build();
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results